# in OOP what is the real internal payload of methods of classes

Tags: oop, methods

I program for few years now and I have a question concerning the internal functioning of methods when we create an object.

So when we create objects in POO each object got its own attributes. but in fact they all share the same methods so how does it work internally ? do methods point on the same address for example in C++ and in this case if we consider a class with tones of methods and no attributes, what is the memory "payload" of creating a lot of object from that class?

In other words do the program duplicate the address points of all methods for each object or is there any other internal functioning to make them reach their methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different languages can implement this differently. In C++ case, imagine the compiler takes your class methods and converts them to free functions. For conversion it add `this` as the first parameter.

C++

```
class A
{
public:
    void f(bool b);

    // and other members
};

A a;
a.f(true);
```

converts to something like:

```
struct A
{
    // other members
}

void a_f(A* this, bool b);

A a;
a_f(&a, true);
```

So now we have a `C` program, no OOP to get confused with.

Comment: Ok great ! An other clue could had been a kind of singleton (a main class) with the methods only and something like a reference to that main class on all objects but we are close to what you express here. Thank you so much